# Edit Service References client config file in silverlight by programmatcally

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, configuration, xap

i am making an application in silverlight.The XAP folder of that application contains ServiceReferencesClientConfig file.I have deployed that application on webserver and whenever i am accessing that website from other machine like `(http://192.168.1.15/SampleApplication/Login.aspx)`, I want to write that IP address(192.168.1.15) into  ServiceReferencesClientConfig and after that the Xap file should be downloaded to client side. But i am not getting idea of editing the ServiceReferencesClientConfig  file by programmatically.  (I want to do that change as i change the IP address of webserver on which application is deployed, it should change the ServiceReferencesClientConfig  automatically so there is no need to to change ServiceReferencesClientConfig file manually.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, you can configure your service proxies dinamically, changing the default constructor to use dinamically generated endpoints and bindings, or using a factory to do the same:

```
public MyService()
        : base(ServiceEx.GetBasicHttpBinding(), ServiceEx.GetEndpointAddress<T>())
{
}



public static class ServiceEx
{
    private static string hostBase;
    public static string HostBase
    {
        get
        {
            if (hostBase == null)
            {
                hostBase = System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri;
                hostBase = hostBase.Substring(0, hostBase.IndexOf("ClientBin"));
                hostBase += "Services/";
            }
            return hostBase;
        }
    }

    public static EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress<TServiceContractType>()
    {
        var contractType = typeof(TServiceContractType);

        string serviceName = contractType.Name;

        // Remove the 'I' from interface names
        if (contractType.IsInterface && serviceName.FirstOrDefault() == 'I')
            serviceName = serviceName.Substring(1);

        serviceName += ".svc";

        return new EndpointAddress(HostBase + serviceName);
    }

    public static Binding GetBinaryEncodedHttpBinding()
    {
        // Binary encoded binding
        var binding = new CustomBinding(
           new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement(),
           new HttpTransportBindingElement()
           {
               MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
               MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue
           }
        );

        SetTimeouts(binding);

        return binding;
    }

    public static Binding GetBasicHttpBinding()
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

        SetTimeouts(binding);

        return binding;
    }
}
```